# Simple way for rounding away from zero?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

With Math.floor, .round. .ceil and .trunc all not directly applicable, is there a simple/standard expression in JavaScript for rounding away from zero, other than comparison using Math.sign?

Eg.

```
 1.2 -> 2
-1.2 -> -2
```

Comment: .ceil rounds toward positive infinity, so -1.2 -> -1

Comment: `n > 0 ? Math.ceil(n) : Math.floor(n)`

Comment: Just a simple if statement should do it, `num < 0 ? Math.floor(num) : Math.ceil(num)`

Comment: I was definitely going overboard with my Math.sign for this example, true :)

Comment: shorter `Math[n < 0 ? 'floor' : 'ceil'](n)`